# How to import XML file into MariaDB database?

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I have a problem. My PHP script not working and I dont know why. This is XML file:

http://itoffice.sk/toto.xml

And this is my PHP code for read XML:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("toto.xml") or die("feed sa nepodarilo načítať");
$id  = $xml->Zbozi['kod_zbozi'];
echo $id;
```

This not working. I need show and write into MySQL all attributes of **<Zbozi>**

<Zbozi> example:

```
<Zbozi diffgr:id="Zbozi1" msdata:rowOrder="0" kod_zbozi="DL139A" popis="HP DMS-59 to Dual DVI Cable Kit,accessory" part_number="DL139A" zaruka="24" dostupnost="false" dph="20" cena="29.23" cenaEU="35.34" snimek="DL139A/06_s.jpg" kod_vyrobce="093-001453" kod_kategorie="PC STOLNÍ POČÍTAČE" kategorie="Stolné počítače" kod_podkategorie="PŘÍSLUŠENSTVÍ ZN PC" podkategorie="Príslušenstvo značkových PC" typ="0" aut_poplatek="0.000" rema="0.000" sam_neprodejne="0" sn_vydej="false" ean="808736662901" doprodej="false">
```

Help me please. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your script was not working, is because you weren't following the XML tree properly. As you can see, your XML's structure looks like this:

```
<diffgr:diffgram>
    <Cenik>
        <Zbozi></Zbozi>
        ...
        <Zbozi></Zbozi>
    </Cenik>
</diffgr:diffgram>
```

Therefore you would have to follow that tree, and then loop for the `Zbozi` elements in order to get all of their attributes.

Take a look at this code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://itoffice.sk/toto.xml');
$zbozi = $xml->children('diffgr', TRUE)->diffgram->children()->Cenik->Zbozi;

$id_arr = array();

foreach ($zbozi as $zbozi_element)
{
    $id_arr[] = (string) $zbozi_element['kod_zbozi'];
}
```

First we load the XML file, nothing new there. But in the second line, we are traversing down the XML file. First we set the prefix namespace to `diffgr` (because of the semicolon in `diffgr:diffgram`), then we simply find the `Zbozi` elements, and loop for them.

You can see that in the loop I've added all of the `kod_zbozi` attribute values into an array. You can really do anything you'd like with that information at this point, this was just to get you started.

Comment: Brother, please what is this? `Fatal error: Call to a member function children() on a non-object `